# Netbeans 8.2 Bad Editor Text

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

Just installed Netbeans IDE 8.2 today and this happened

[image: Ugly, bad formatted text in the Editor]

Search through many forums, still can't find the answer. I tried to change the font, but still can't work.

**My System :**

- Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)
- Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 1
- Java: 1.8.0_112; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.112-b15
- Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_112-b15
- System: Windows 8.1 version 6.3 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)

**Question:**

How can I fix this? And what does that red line do?

Comment: Try a different editor font.

Comment: I've tried some fonts, Consolas and Segoe UI looks good but still a little bit abnormal.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I've tried some fonts, Consolas and Segoe UI looks good but still a little bit abnormal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found a solution, despite it isn't a perfect solution for this problem.

I tried to change the font to Consolas, and it looks 99% normal.

[Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3979.png)

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Pick a profile (Reset if you have made changes to it) and you should be good to go!